# How can I add a column into an array SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset using an array that looks like this:

```
data have;
set qty_wide;
by ID; 
       do=I to dim(qty)-1) to 1 by -1;
          qty[i]=qty[i];
       end;
run;
ID   Date     qty_1   qty_2   qty_3  qty_4  qty_5  
1   10/01/23   1       0       0       0     0      
1   11/01/23   0       1       0       0     0      
1   12/01/23   0       0       1       0     0      
1   01/01/23   0       0       0       1     0       
..
```

And another dataset that looks like this:-

```
ID   Date         amount
1   10/01/23     0.3  
1   01/01/23     0.8
```

I've left join the 'amount' column to the first dataset. I would want to somehow add the amount value to the array values.

```
ID   Date     qty_1   qty_2   qty_3  qty_4  qty_5  amount
1   10/01/23   1.3       0       0       0     0     0.3 
1   11/01/23   0       1       0       0       0      0
1   12/01/23   0       0       1       0       0      0
1   01/01/23   0       0       0       1.8     0     0.8
```

Comment: I don't understand what your question is.  You cannot include variables in an array that do not exist in the data step.  Are you asking how to merge two datasets by the DATE variable?  If so you should sort the data by DATE first so that the merge can work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the arrays have to do with the question.

If you want to merge two datasets then first SORT them.

Example:

```
data one;
  input ID Date :mmddyy. qty_1-qty_5 ;
  format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
1   10/01/23   1       0       0       0     0
1   11/01/23   0       1       0       0     0
1   12/01/23   0       0       1       0     0
1   01/01/23   0       0       0       1     0
;

data two;
  input ID Date :mmddyy. amount;
  format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
1   10/01/23     0.3  
1   01/01/23     0.8
;

proc sort data=one;
  by id date;
run;

proc sort data=two;
  by id date;
run;

data want;
  merge one two;
  by id date;
run;
```

Result

```
ID          Date    qty_1    qty_2    qty_3    qty_4    qty_5    amount

 1    2023-01-01      0        0        0        1        0        0.8
 1    2023-10-01      1        0        0        0        0        0.3
 1    2023-11-01      0        1        0        0        0         .
 1    2023-12-01      0        0        1        0        0         .
```

Answer (score 0):

After the left join you can use a DATA Step to apply the amount to each quantity by using a loop

```
data want;
  set have;
  array q qty:;
  do over q;
    if not missing (q) and q ne 0 then
      q = sum(q,amount);
  end;
run;
```

You can also update in place using the MODIFY statement.  MODIFY does not create new columns (i.e. amount).

Using Tom's data

```
data master;
  input ID Date :mmddyy. qty_1-qty_5 ;
  format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
1   10/01/23   1       0       0       0     0
1   11/01/23   0       1       0       0     0
1   12/01/23   0       0       1       0     0
1   01/01/23   0       0       0       1     0
;

data transact;
  input ID Date :mmddyy. amount;
  format date yymmdd10.;
cards;
1   10/01/23     0.3  
1   01/01/23     0.8
;

proc sort data=transact;
  by id date;

data master;
  modify master;
  set transact;
  by id date;
  array q qty:;
  do over q;
    if not missing (q) and q ne 0 then
      q = sum(q,amount);
  end;
run;
```